# How to make a tabbed activity go full screen in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am trying to make a tabbed activity(with swipe pages) go full screen but its not working....I have tried the way I know to resolve the issue i.e. using,

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

but this crashes my app....*Can anyone walk me through for this, please*?
P.S. I have used fragments to make individual swipe pages.

**Here is the Java file for the Activity**

```
package com.example.neo.introv21;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //No title bar is set for the activity
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //Full screen is set for the Window
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //This is to hide the toolbar that resides on the top of the screen instead
        //of using the fullscreen activity
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       // getSupportActionBar().hide();

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


        /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    page1 pg1_object = new page1();
                    return pg1_object;
                case 1:
                    page2 pg2_object = new page2();
                    return pg2_object;
                case 2:
                    page3 pg3_object = new page3();
                    return pg3_object;
                case 3:
                    page4 pg4_object = new page4();
                    return pg4_object;
                case 4:
                    page5 pg5_object = new page5();
                    return pg5_object;
                case 5:
                    page6 pg6_object = new page6();
                    return pg6_object;
                case 6:
                    page7 pg7_object = new page7();
                    return pg7_object;
                case 7:
                    page8 pg8_object = new page8();
                    return pg8_object;
                case 8:
                    page9 pg9_object = new page9();
                    return pg9_object;

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 9 total pages.
            return 10;
        }
}
```

**This is one of the java file that acts like a fragment to inflate the tabbed activity**

```
public class page1 extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**Supporting XML file for the fragment page**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.neo.introv21.MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ss1"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make any activity go full screen just follow this -
1. Add this theme to styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoTitle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

2. Apply this theme to your activity in manifest

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle"/>
```

3. Override onWindowsFocusChanged in your activity

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {
                    findViewById(android.R.id.content).setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
                }
            }

    }
```

P.S. - If you want action bar for your app do not set below in your theme.

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Comment: It worked!Thanks! Can you tell me is there a way to start an activity from one of the switch cases of getItem() function? When i try to use the intent, it crashes the app.....

Comment: It does work...but on the emulator and physical device alike, its creating an empty white space above and below the image!!Can you guess why that happens?

Comment: that is because you haven't overridden the onWindowFocusChanged() method in your Activity's class @BWashishtha

Comment: getItem() isn't supposed to work like that. As the name suggests, it is used to provide a fragment to the viewpager, so that the viewpager displays the corresponding fragment for a particular position.

Comment: @BWashishtha sorry I misread ur 2nd comment, the reason that there is white space above and below the image is probably because your imageview doesn't spans across the entire screen. Its width and height is set to wrap content.